# How to configure subversion, for web application development, to limit developer access to source code

Tags: php, git, svn, web-applications, version-control

My team has been working on a web application based on php, msql for backend and html,css,jquery for front end. We have been working for quite sometime now without version control. The project has become quite large and complicated now and feel that it is time to use some sort of version control ( vc ).

We have been reading quite a lot about vc and have found several techniques that people have suggested. although it might be a perfect method for them. it does not effectively apply to our case.

our application is split up into various modules and we have outsourced work to a few freelancers. freelancers work independently over front end or back end depending on their skill. *The work has been happening over a Private Network so far and we would like to shift to an online system.*

Now the problem is that we cannot distribute the source code for the entire project to all developers. developers are only allowed to work on some common libraries and their respective modules.

Hence we cannot allow the entire project to be downloaded onto each developers Local machine. Thus we need to find a way for all developers to be working on the same branch OR on the trunk. to be able to access only certain sections of the code and on saves/commits be able to check how their changes have effected instantly.

Is there a way the above task can be achieved ? for a web application ? using a version control like subversion?

**To summarize, the features we are trying to implement are as follows.**

1. **Instant effects on save/commit** *( When each developer saves/commits they should be able to test the effects like normal through the browser instantly )*
2. **Limited access** *( Each developer can access only a specific part of the project and not the whole project. )*
3. **Online repository / Online copy** - *( we are working on a VPN connection, and would like to have the website work on an online copy. so when a commit is made, the developer can view his changes online instead of the VPN  )*

---

after a lot of searching online we were able to find the below possibilities. But not sure if it is the right way to go.

1. For instant effects --> *Entire system is checked out in a webroot folder ( eg. wamp/www/projectName ), a bat file is called to update the current system in the webroot, everytime a commit is made, by using the post-commit hook.*
2. Limited access --> *All development for all developers happen in the trunk OR a Development branch, developers can access their respective sections, lock it if needed and commit changes when they are ready to see its effects ( note still in dev branch ).*
3. tags are created whenever a stable release is created. these Tagged copies are never modified.

Is such a configuration achievable using subversion or should we look at other open-source version control tools ?

Answer (score 3):

Trying to prevent devs from accessing the entire source tree seems a bit misguided to me. Is it company politics? Don't you trust your developers?

In any case..

The easiest way to achieve what you want would probably be to put each module into its own repository (svn, git, whatever). Then you can selectively choose who has access to which repo.

Comment: Its not company politics, we completely trust our in house developers. but a lot of the work is outsourced to 3rd party freelancers and unknown programmers over the internet. it wont take much for the code to be misused, We have invested a lot in terms of time and money and would not like to take a chance for all of it to be undone. so its not really about trust, just being safe. the business owners require the code to be proprietary, hence the precaution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Post-commit hook, which **unconditionally** "do site" is in a common *not-so-good idea*: developer can commit semi-finished code and even don't think about testing it
2. Make your Working Copy public, when site became public - *not-so-good idea* from the POV of security and IP. For SVN 1.7 to move WC-root outside web-root is much better idea
3. If modules are splitted to different directories, you can create repository per module and "super-repository", which, with svn:externals, combine repositories in Project
4. Path-access inside tree can be easy controlled (in http-repo) by authz_svn_module
5. **Enable** creating private **personal short-time branches for developers** ("shelves"), it helps to avoid (with 1) huge messed up commits

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i didn't quite understand the first 2 points you made. could you elaborate a bit more on it ?

so then if i should not write the hook to update the web root folder on commit, how else can i have a live testable copy at any time which would be concurrent for all developers ?

I was thinking something like a development/trunk branch that will update the webroot on every commit. and when the dev branch is stable move it to a test branch and then create a tag for a version release after it passes all tests. does this work better ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd recommend reading the "Continuous Delivery" book (website [here](http://continuousdelivery.com/)). It provides many examples for how to set up this kind of thing.

Secondly, yes, SVN allows you to [assign permissions on a folder level](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) as well as repo level (but read the "do you really want to do this" section).

Thirdly, making sure developers have up to date copies is something you should instill by discipline - "before starting work, and before committing, run svn update"). Post-commit hooks have a nasty habit of breaking stuff, and you're not preventing commits which break the build.

Fourthly, I'd consider setting up a continuous integration server (also described in the Continuous Delivery book). This makes sure you have a clean, working build whenever you put together the work of your developers.